# Converting Arraylist to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, converters, toarray

I need help trying to convert an arraylist to an array. I am having trouble doing so, If anyone can show me where to implement the (.toarray) piece of code.

```
public class BFFHelper 
{
ArrayList<BestFriends> myBFFs;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public BFFHelper()
{
    myBFFs = new ArrayList<BestFriends>();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, implement it?  Where do you want the conversion to be done?

Comment: You just call the [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-) method. What's the problem?

Comment: should i put it inside the public BFFHelper() method? 
is 
public BFFHelper()
{
 myBFFs = new ArrayList<BestFriends>();
myBFFs.toArray(BestFriends);
} 
ok?